# My app unfortunately stops when running on API 16 to 24 but runs on API 25 upwards

Tags: android, genymotion

I am building a book app targeting from API 16 upward but always have this error when running it in API 16 - 24 emulators. It only loads correctly without error when running on API 25 - 27 emulators. However it runs correctly on the API 16 up emulators when i exclude the ImageView Widget. How do i solve this because i need the ImageView to be functional in the app. this is the activity_main.xml text for the image view and layout.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/getstarted"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,3:2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wclnote2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logoview" /> 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center|fill"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.godwinacquah.studybuddy"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
       buildTypes {
            release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
             }
       }
      android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
       }

     dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0- 
     beta3'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
     core:3.0.1'
     implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
     }
```

this is the full layout xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="center|fill"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wlcnote1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/note1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wclnote2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/note2"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wlcnote1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/getstarted"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Get Started"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/getstarted"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,3:2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wclnote2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logoview" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post your gradle file too.

Comment: What's the error logcat?

Comment: May be the reason is, you are defining the ImageView on top of ConstrainLayout, or, add this line above ImageView
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Answer (score 0):

May be the reason is, you are defining the ImageView on top of ConstrainLayout, or, add this line above ImageView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/getstarted"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,3:2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wclnote2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logoview" /> 


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center|fill"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: i added the line of code before the ImageView but generated an error                                                                         "build failed 1m 24s 999ms
Starting Gradle Daemon 8s 348ms
Run build 40s 664ms
Load build 3s 227ms
Configure build 27s 683ms
Calculate task graph 310ms
Run tasks 8s 231ms
null 
C:/Users/GODWIN ACQUAH/AndroidStudioProjects/StudyBuddy 
app/src/main/res 
layout/activity_main.xml 
error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity. "

Comment: First of all there is no point of having 2 Constraint Layout, but still if you want to use like that, then try my edited answer. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center|fill"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/getstarted"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,3:2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wclnote2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logoview" /> 

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```